# Updating xml file using xml script in msbuild

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, msbuild

I want to replace some text in existing XML file. For example, I want to replace the text `/product_release/` with `/product_release_version_number`. I want to modify the XML file in place without creating another XML file with the updated value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Explain what is this xml and what are you going to change exaclty.

You can add some code to prebuild/postbuild event (project properties -> Build Events) and type any cmd command and use predefined variables clicking on Macros buttons (it's funny but some of the aren't in list like $(MsBuildTaskPath)).

You have some big action to perform on build you should use msbuild tasks. You can create them yourselft on c# or use deafult tasks from VS or community tasks (http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/).
You can also use macros var here and use Exec task for any cmd commands.

It's too large for comment thats why i posted it as an answer